# Can you turn off the loading screen in Submodal?

Tags: javascript, scripting, popup, lightbox

We are using the enhanced sub-modal script (http://gabrito.com/files/subModal/) and would like to bypass the loading.html screen that comes up by default. Can this be turned off? Setting the value to "null" shows a "page not found" error before the actual page loads.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard, but the code is scattered all over the place in the Javascript source. You might want to use a more modern alternative instead (especially if you're already using a library on your site)

First of all, we strip out all instances of the `gLoading` variable - this means removing the `setPopUpLoadingPage` function and the `src="'+gLoading+'"` in the part where they build the HTML string to inject into the page. And finally, one last reference to `gLoading` exist in the `hidePopWin` function, to reset the iframe source back to the loading page when the modal is hidden.

Then finally we replace the line `gPopFrame.src = url;` in the `showPopWin` function with this:

```
if(gPopFrame.src != url){
    gPopFrame.src = url;
}
```

To stop the iframe from reloading if it's the same source.

You can see a live demo of the new script here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/T2u2Z/ and also grab a copy of it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/submodalsource.js